Setting AWS SQS credentials with Cognito Userpool
I'm trying to send a message to SQS with the Javascript v3 SDK, using Cognito already logged in user session credentials.
Cognito login
This works fine and I can use the session IdToken and AccessToken with no problem to authenticate with Api Agteway, for example.
window.authToken = new Promise(function fetchCurrentAuthToken(resolve, reject) {
            cognitoUser.getSession(function sessionCallback(err, session) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else if (!session.isValid()) {
                    resolve(null);
                } else {
                    resolve(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
                    console.log(session.getIdToken());
                    window.token = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                    window.logged_user = decodeJWT(token);  

                    let credentials = {
                      accessToken: session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(),
                      idToken: token,
                    };     

                    sendMessageToSQS(token, 'Oh yes baby', credentials)

                };
            });
        });

SQS
Then I try to send a message with the following function, but I get the error that credentials object is not valid.
function sendMessageToSQS(idToken, messageBody, credentials) {

    let sqsClient = new SQSClient({
        'region': 'ap-southeast-2',
        'credentials': credentials
    });

    const params = {
      'QueueUrl': "myQueueUrl",
      'MessageBody': messageBody,
    };

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': idToken,
    };

    const command = new SendMessageCommand(params);
    const response = sqsClient.send(command, { headers });
    console.log("Message sent:", response);
};

I found diverse and confusing information about this. Wht should the "credentials" for the SQS request should look like?
